# Resistor dissipating 0.1W in heatshrink tubing

Tags: power-dissipation

I have made a LED lamp by soldering together a 3mm red LED and a 1K resistor form [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-1-4W-1-Metal-Film-Resistors-30-Values-Resistance-Assortment-Kit-300pcs-Set-/261961772400?hash=item3cfe236d70:g:0LIAAOSwjVVVnx1l). I then wrapped it in heatshrink, to insulate it and make it look nice. But now I've done some maths and I realized that the resistor will have to dissipate 0.1W (12V power supply -> 10V/1KOhm=10mA -> 10V*10mA=0.1W) and I am worried that it might run a bit too hot and malfunction (cause a fire).

Am I right to worry or will it be fine? It has been on for about an hour now and it is only a little warm on the outside (probably not even 30°C), but I don't know what thermal resistance it has.

Comment: Can you tell us the resistor's power rating? If you can't, put a photo of it so that we can determine its size. I'm asking this, because if you're using a standard 0.25W resistor then nothing to worry about. Of course it can get a bit hot (nothing higher than 50°C), but it does not cause a fire.

Comment: It's a 1/4W resistor from a kit sold on ebay: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-1-4W-1-Metal-Film-Resistors-30-Values-Resistance-Assortment-Kit-300pcs-Set-/261961772400?hash=item3cfe236d70:g:0LIAAOSwjVVVnx1l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get into some maths here about the thermal resistance of heat shrink tubing but you are worrying unnecessarily. If the outside is 30C the inside is not going to more than 50C.